# get the count of the same values in foreach loop PHP

Tags: php, foreach

I have an array of repeated values of same column and different values of same column.So i'm trying get the one final array which can contains all the data.

Actual array:

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => {#820 ▼
    +"id": 318
    +"asset_id": 11
    +"job_id": 37
    +"asset_name": "Mini Paver"
    +"shift": "AM
  }
  1 => {#819 ▼
    +"id": 319
    +"asset_id": 39
    +"job_id": 37
    +"asset_name": "Road Sweeper"
    +"shift": "AM
  }
  2 => {#701 ▼
    +"id": 320
    +"asset_id": 11
    +"job_id": 37
    +"asset_name": "Mini Paver"
    +"shift": "AM
  }
  3 => {#825 ▼
    +"id": 321
    +"asset_id": 39
    +"job_id": 37
    +"asset_name": "Road Sweeper"
    +"shift": "AM

  }
]
```

and by using below for each loop I'm trying to get the one array out of four.

```
 $jobArr = array();
  foreach ($job_data as $data) {

            $jobArr[$data['job_id']]['job_id']       = $data->job_id;
            $jobArr[$data['job_id']]['shift']        = $data->shift;
            $jobArr[$data['job_id']]['asset_name'][] = $data->asset_name;

        }
```

and output for the above foreach is as below

```
array:1 [▼
  37 => array:8 [▼
    "job_id" => 37
    "shift" => "AM"
    "asset_name" => array:2 [▼
      0 => "Road Sweeper "
      1 => "Mini Paver "
    ]
  ]
]
```

Actually I need to get the count as well like how many asset names are there with the same name which should look like below

```
array:1 [▼
  37 => array:8 [▼
    "job_id" => 37
    "shift" => "AM"
    "asset_name" => array:2 [▼
      0 => "Road Sweeper (2)"
      1 => "Mini Paver (2)"
    ]
  ]
]
```

How do i get the count of same asset_name and the result array as like same above. Any suggestions please.

Comment: A well placed $count++ would do it.

Comment: Didi you run your code? It can't work because you use $data['job_id'] together with $data->job_id and give as not correct result of such code

Comment: @Andrew : how $count++ will work ?

Comment: @splash58 : Yes I ran the code. But any suggestions from your side ?

Comment: *Yes I ran the code* - what is result you get?

Comment: @splash58: solved it thank you

Answer (score 0):

After you've built your grouped array as shown, you can iterate it and use `array_count_values` to generate an array in the new format, then replace the `asset_name` array with the new array.

```
foreach ($jobArr as $job_id => $job) {

    // iterate the counted values and build your array with the desired format
    foreach(array_count_values($job['asset_name']) as $asset => $count) {
        $counts[] = "$asset ($count)";
    }

    // replace the old asset_name key with your new counted/formatted array
    $jobArr[$job_id]['asset_name'] = $counts;
}
```

Comment: It gives me error like this `array_count_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given`

Comment: Hm? In your example of current output shown above, `$job['asset_name']` _is_ an array.

Comment: Yes its an array. and it comes proper for one job_id , if it has multiple then the job_id all asset_names is carry forwarding to next job_id and so on.